# How to click a Xamarin element with javascript in Appium?

Tags: javascript, xamarin, xamarin.forms, appium, appium-android

I feel like I'm going a little insane.

How do you click on an accessibility element in javascript using Appium? I have created a Xamarin app. I've put a button on the main page with an AutomationID == "ClickHere!!!". I want to click this button.

Here is the entire appium code:

```
const wdio = require("webdriverio");

const opts = {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
      platformName: "Android",
      platformVersion: "9",
      deviceName: "<device name>",
      app: "<path to apk>",
      appPackage: "<packagename>",
      appActivity: "<MainActivity from Xamarin>",
      automationName: "UiAutomator2"
    }
  };
  
  async function main () {
    const client = await wdio.remote(opts);
    
    //Click the button somehow

    await client.deleteSession();
  }
  
  main();
```

When I try to find the element with Appium I either get a `NoSuchElementException` or a 'Click is not a function' error. **I am able to boot the app up and run the test, I just can't click on an element / button**

I'm a noob to Appium so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in webdriverio or most javascript based system the out put of all actions are promises . so you have to use await

```
  async function main () {
    const client = await wdio.remote(opts);

    let element = await $("locator")
    await element.click()

    //you can also use it as :
    
    await (await $("locator")).click()
    //Click the button somehow

    await client.deleteSession();
  }
```